# ¿Cómo puedo editar mi info de perfil?

Tags: soporte, perfil

Deseo modificar mi perfil en este sitio (el de español), pero no encuentro si es posible eso, ¿o aún no tengo privilegios?

Answer (score 3):

1. Debes acceder a tu cuanta e ir a la pagina principal https://es.stackoverflow.com

2. Haz **click** en tu perfil

   [image: Click en la barra superior]

3. Haz **click** donde dice "Edición de perfil y configuración"

   [image: En el tab superior]

4. Haz **click** donde dice "Cambiar imagen"

   [image: Primera opción al editar el perfil]

   Desde aquí ya que no es tan complicado cargar una imagen o modificar tus datos.

5. Luego de editar el perfil, en el pie, permite guardar los cambios para toda la red de SE o sólo para esta comunidad (SOes).

   [image: Guardar cambios solo para esta comunidad | Guardar cambios y copiarlos a todas las comunidades de Stack Exchange]